# Xcode 4 : Re-signing the xcode archive for release

Tags: xcode4, code-signing

My client wants to submit the project by himself so he asked me to get the xcode `xcarchive` of the project and send him to sign it and upload it.

He gave me his development certificate, I installed it and sign the target with its provision profile.

The build configuration that I'm using for signing is a copy of **"Release"**.

Now when he tries to resign the archive and submit it, iTunes throw an error **Invalid Binary** and the culprit is the **Signature**

Its says :

> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a
>   distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development
>   certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are
>   correct at the target level (which override any values at the project
>   level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built
>   using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are
>   certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in
>   Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your
>   release target. Once you have corrected these issues, go to the app's
>   version details page (found in the Manage Your Applications module of
>   iTunes Connect) and click Ready to Submit Binary. Proceed through the
>   submission process until the app's status is Waiting for Upload. You
>   can then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

Do I need the private key used by my client?

Can someone please point me to the right direction? Can I get any tutorial or video how to resign the archive and submit it to the store.

Comment: Please take the time to use proper formatting. It helps us help you by making your question easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask your client to generate a distribution certificate and then sign your project with it.

Comment: he has the distribution certificate and the validation went flawlessly.. but after upload iTunes ended up saying INVALID BINARY.